# Objective-C - boolean attributes -> map an image

Tags: objective-c

I have an iPad application and I have an object with five attributes of type bool. I have an UIImageView where I have to put an image into depending which of these attributes is true. This is my source code which works fine:

```
if (myObject.attribute1) {
    myCell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"imageForAttribute1.png"];
} else if (myObject.attribute2) {
    myCell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"imageForAttribute2.png"];
} else if (myObject.attribute3) {
    myCell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"imageForAttribute3.png"];
} else if (myObject.attribute4) {
    myCell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"imageForAttribute4.png"];
} else if (myObject.attribute5) {
    myCell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"imageForAttribute5.png"];
}
```

For me, it looks not so nice. Isn't there a nicer way to solve this "problem"?

Best Regards, Tim.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are the attributes all truly independent? Based on the logic you're showing, it seems that you're expecting that only one attribute will be set at a time.

If that's the case, maybe the attributes could be combined into a single enum value, with possible values of 1-5, then you could just use that number to select the image:

```
 NSString *imageName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"imageForAttribute%d.png", attr];
 myCell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:imageName];
```